# Vídeo auto ajustavel

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Bom estou utilizando `HTML5` que por sua vez possui uma tag chamada `<video>` só que estou tendo muitas dificuldades para utilizar o meu vídeo no header do meu site pois não consigo manipular meu vídeo corretamente gostaria que meu vídeo fica-se como o desse [site](http://www.popupdesign.com.br/)
 eu ate consigo porem eu tenho que colocar os valores da altura no meu código logo se pego uma tela menor o vídeo fica grande se coloco numa tela maior meu vídeo fica pequeno percebam que o vídeo desse site ai ele e auto ajustável ele e sempre 100% de largura e altura segue um exemplo da forma que eu fiz porem nao muito certa pois chumbar valores de altura com a tag `transform:scale();` eu acho que é errado:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  min-height: 850px;
}
video {
  height: 760.4375px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scaley(1.72);
  -o-transform: scaley(1.72);
  -ms-transform: scaley(1.72);
  -moz-transform: scaley(1.72);
  transform: scaley(1.72);
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
}
#bg-video {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/overlay.png);
  z-index: 1
}
.texto-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -280px;
  width: 630px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #FFF;
}
.texto-header h1 {
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 4em;
}
.texto-header strong {
  color: #f80;
}
.texto-header p {
  /*font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;*/
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: -5%;
}
.texto-header a {
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 13px;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.texto-header a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="video">
    <video id="Video1" class="bgvid" loop autoplay>
      <source src="video/League-warrios.mp4" type="video/mp4" />desculpe mais seu navegador não suporta este formato ou esta desatualizado :(
    </video>
  </div>
  <div id="bg-video"></div>

  <div class="texto-header">
    <h1>Olá amigos somos a <strong>Nova Era !</strong></h1>
    <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque.
      <br>Cras sit amet ligula ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus, mollis sit amet vehicula id, volutpat eget mauris.</p>
    <br/>
    <a href="#circulo">Então podemos começar ???</a>
  </div>



</header>
```

OBS: O meu vídeo possui um background igual o do site mencionado acima que se chama overlay e não me importo se tiver que manipular o vídeo via java script pois já não sei mais oque fazer para chegar no resultado que desejo

Comment: Você tem que procurar informações sobre media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal achei a resposta consegui fazer vou responder meu propio post porque caso alguém precise disso um dia esse post poderá ajudar:

```
<div id="video-bg">
      <video autoplay loop id="volume-js">
        <!-- Default video source: -->
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video/myvid.mp4"
                media="(orientation:landscape)">
      </video>
    </div>
```

o css:

```
#video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bg-video{
  background-image: url(../images/overlay.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#video-bg > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}

/* 1. No object-fit support: */
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #video-bg > video { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #video-bg > video { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}

/* 2. If supporting object-fit, overriding (1): */
@supports (object-fit: cover) {
  #video-bg > video {
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

esse código vai deixar o vídeo full screen 100% x 100% sem perder resolução ou qualidade ele não estica o vídeo e nem distorce (porem o vídeo tem que ser de qualidade) =3